# Ответ "Да или "Нет" для продолжения игры

Tags: java

Не судите строго учу Java третий день, решил создать программку для фана, после завершения игры, хочу что бы выводился вопрос: хотите продолжить или нет? Если ответ" да" то бы игра началась заново, если ответ "нет" то всего доброго.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Bender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int summa;
        String stavka;
        System.out.println("Сделайте вашу ставку, вы можете поставить на красное или черное, четное или не не четное, или на определленое число.");
        stavka = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Какую сумму ставите?");
        summa = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            int b;
            String[] colour = {"Черное.", "Красное."};
            Random random = new Random();
            Random random1 = new Random();
            int select = random.nextInt(colour.length);
            b = (random1.nextInt(36));
            if (b == 0) {
                System.out.print("");
            } else if ((b & 1) == 0) {
                System.out.print(" Выпало четное" + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Выпало нечетное" + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(b + " " + colour[select]);
        }

            String otvet;
            int znach = 1;
            if (stavka.equals("Красное")) {
                System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
            } else if (stavka.equals("Черное")) {
                System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
            } else if (stavka.equals("Не четное")) {
                System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
            } else if (stavka.equals("Четное")) {
                System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили!Выиграшь составляет:" + summa * 2);
            } else

            System.out.println("Вы проиграли,делаем ставку еще раз?");
            otvet = scanner.next();
            if (otvet.equals("Да")) {
                System.out.println("Продолжаем!");
            } else if (otvet.equals("Нет")) ;
            System.out.println("Жаль(До Встречи!");
        }

    }
```

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: @Roman - надо писать не *JAVA*, а *Java*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - можете вынести раунд в отдельную функцию, и вызывать ее до тех пор, пока глобальная переменная `true` (не проверял на ide):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Bender {

static boolean playAgain = true;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         while (playAgain) {
             Game(); /* вызов игры */
         }
     }

    public static void Game() {
            /* весь остальной код */ 
            playAgain = false; //тут храним ответ игрока - да или нет
            System.out.println("Вы проиграли,делаем ставку еще раз?");
            otvet = scanner.next();
            if (otvet.equals("Да")) {
                System.out.println("Продолжаем!");
                playAgain = true;
            } else if (otvet.equals("Нет")) ;
            System.out.println("Жаль(До Встречи!");
        }

    }
}
```

Способ не совсем красивый, но с минимальным исправлением кода.

Comment: Не работает, play again подсвечиваеться красным цветом, когда навожу курсор, пишет это:Non-static field 'playAgain' cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: @Roman добавьте слово `static` перед `boolean`, см. ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующий подход для реализации такой логики.

1. Обернуть вашу игру в класс, например `Game`. В цикле создаем объект данного класса.
2. Для старта игры, вызвать соответствующий метод, например `start`
3. После того как игра завершена, выйти из метода `start`. Затем спросить игрока, хочет ли он продолжить.
   Если вопрос утвердительный, создаем еще раз объект и переходим **к шагу 2**, иначе завершаем программу - **выйдя из цикла**.

На псевдокоде это будет выглядеть так:

```
while(true){
     Game game = new Game();
     game.start();

     System.out.println("хотите сыграть еще?")
     if (ответ отрицательный)
         break;
}
```